# Single verb for multiple subjects vs multiple verbs for multiple subjects

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, passive-voice

I have different things to do. I would like to express this in a passive voice. I would like to understand the correct way to do this in English.

> Suppose that a model A is given, fitted to the simulated data and estimated.

or

> Suppose that a model A is given, is fitted to the simulated data and is estimated.

Do I need to repeat the verb or a single verb is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to repeat the auxiliary verb:

> A model is given and fitted to the data.

But I note that you do not "Estimate a model", instead you "use a model to estimate (the parameters)". So the "...and estimated" is grammatically correct, but doesn't fit the meaning. I would write

> ... and used to estimate ....